# any documentation for writing a custom git merge strategy?

Tags: git, merge

There's certain binary file types that I have written my own code to merge cleanly. I've tried to add my own merge strategy by adding a merge command line with a driver in .gitconfig and adding a file expression in .gitattributes to point to my merge program.

And it works - if I do a git merge with that file type, it calls my program - if I exit with 1 it fails and says there's a conflict - if 0 it succeeds.

HOWEVER - I can't find any documentation on how it gets parameters - ie how do I know what file is being merged - what file it's being merged with etc.   They aren't coming in as environment variables...    I know on the driver command line I can put some variables, but with trial and error, $PWD is the only one that I've found that works.

Can anyone point me to any documentation about how to write a custom merge strategy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer is in two parts, because what you have described is not a *merge strategy* but rather a *merge driver*.

#### Merge strategies

I don't think there is any proper documentation.  There is only the source code.  You can get a good high level overview of how the strategies work using `GIT_TRACE`, though, because `git merge` computes some information and then runs `git-merge-recursive` or `git-merge-octopus` or whatever other `-s <strategy>` you've selected.  If you write your own `git-merge-oakey` command, and run `git merge -s oakey`, you can view the arguments.

#### Merge drivers

Your merge driver is invoked in the way described in [the gitattributes documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) (search for **Defining a custom merge driver**).  The `%`-character substitutions will fill in the various arguments.  As it says, wherever you write `%O`, `%A`, or `%B`, Git will fill in the name of a temporary file that holds the data from the appropriate index stage (copied out to an ordinary file in the work-tree).  You're expected to overwrite the file that `%A` names.

> how do I know what file is being merged ...

You *don't know* (and cannot tell) which *file name* is being merged; you're expected to complete your job using only the three input *contents*.  Ultimately, there isn't necessarily a single file name anyway: Git may have detected a rename on one side of the merge, so that the file is named `foo` in the merge base and on one side, and `bar` on the other side.  (As [Hasturkun noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54528824/any-documentation-for-writing-a-custom-git-merge-strategy/54531001?noredirect=1#comment95876837_54531001), the `%P` placeholder will expand to whichever name Git is going to use as its best guess for the final path-name.  Do not use this as one of the three inputs to the merge process, though—the three inputs are in the `%O`, `%A`, and `%B` files.)

Comment: The gitattributes documentation also gives `%P`, which gives the pathname where the merged result will be stored. (Probably still not helpful across renames)

Comment: @Hasturkun: oops, yes, I should have mentioned that.

Comment: cool - thanks - that's exactly what I wanted - it's the %O %A etc that I couldn't find.